# Sull'uso dell'espressione "senza fare concessioni di restituire all'utente" in un testo giornalistico

Tags: word-usage

Su [questo sito web](http://spaghettibcn.com/20170202_carmen-consoli-concerto-barcellona-ciclo-jamboritalia.html) ho letto questa frase:

> Fedele al suo spirito inquieto e una forte personalità, Consoli ha combinato il suo gusto per l’eccellenza con un’estetica pop che collega il presente con le sue canzoni **senza fare concessioni di restituire all’utente** o superficialità musicale.

Non riesco ad afferrare il senso dell'espressione "senza fare concessioni di restituire all'utente", malgrado capire il significato delle singole parole.

**Aggiornamento della domanda:**

I vostri commenti da madrelingua mi hanno fatto vedere che la domanda interessante in questo caso non è quella di cercare di capire il senso esatto di questa espressione usata dall'autore del testo (questo è forse impossibile), ma quella di spiegare il fenomeno linguistico che c'è dietro questo modo di redigere un articolo giornalistico. Si potrebbe dire che è un esempio di uno "stile giornalistico" più o meno caratteristico di certi blog scritti da non professionisti del giornalismo? In questo caso concreto, succede che l'[autore dell'articolo](http://www.voglioviverecosi.com/spaghettibcn-il-blog-degli-italiani-di-barcellona.html) è un analista programmatore che si occupa di applicazioni web, gestione di siti, marketing online, ecc. Quindi penso che probabilmente per questa ragione usi termini come "utente", che sono più adatti a contesti professionali propri del suo mestiere.

Comment: È probabilmente un refuso. Se dovessi indovinare direi che *di resitituire all'utente* è rimasto nella frase per sbaglio, ma in ogni caso non si tratta di un italiano proprio esemplare.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Beh... è l'italiano degli [italiani che vivono a Barcellona](http://spaghettibcn.com/about) :(

Comment: Dal link citato già *cantantessa* non si può sentire. Poi al paragrafo successivo c'è anche un *suoi* che è diventato *suo*. Probabilmente il lavoro giornalistico non è il primario interesse del redattore dell'articolo.

Comment: ...probabilmente la lingua italiana non è il primario interesse del redattore dell'articolo.

Comment: Solo una piccola nota linguistica: "cantantessa" è la parola che la stessa Consoli usa per definirsi. È nata da un qui pro quo (http://palermo.repubblica.it/cronaca/2015/03/09/news/carmen_consoli_ritorno_in_sicilia_e_tempo_di_dire_grazie_alla_mia_terra_-109127700/?ref=twhl&utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter)

Comment: La mia opinione è che *senza fare concessioni di restituire all'utente* non significa nulla. Forse voleva dire *senza concessioni all'ascoltatore o superficialità musicale*.

Comment: OP, queste domande da fonti di pessima qualità vanno evitate. Suvvia...

Comment: @Bruno9779: Scusa, non sono italiana: sto facendo un corso di italiano alla Scuola Ufficiale di Lingue di Barcellona. Qualche volta abbiamo dato un'occhiata a questo sito web: ci può essere utile per avere informazioni su alcuni eventi che accadono nella mia città e che riguardano la cultura italiana. Mi dispiace davvero che questo articolo sia mal scritto (questo significa che a qualche italiano che abita a Barcellona andrebbe anche bene fare un corso di italiano)...

Comment: @Bruno9779: Tuttavia, non essendo italiana, è molto difficile per me leggere un'espressione che non conosco e che non capisco e accorgermi che si tratta di qualcosa che non si usa. Ho bisogno del vostro aiuto per poter imparare questo. E per chiedervelo, devo poter porre la domanda.

Comment: A chiunque abbia votato di chiudere perché OT: per quanto l'articolo possa essere orribile, è pur sempre un brano scritto in italiano il cui significato Charo cercava di capire. Cosa c'è di OT in questo?

Comment: @DenisNardin in casi come questo, dove la domanda nasce da un errore ortografico/grammaticale, la scelta ricade tra chiudere come OT e rispondere che si tratta di un errore. Credo che si dovrebbe chiudere per scoraggiare le domande che originano da siti in "italianesco"

Comment: @Bruno9779: Come studentessa di italiano di livello C1, devo essere in grado di capire la lingua usata in tutti i diversi registri. Questo significa che a volte dobbiamo ascoltare persone e leggere testi che non si esprimono in un italiano "perfetto": io dovrei essere in grado di capire anche gli italiani che si esprimono così. Questo non significa che non debba essere consapevole degli errori grammaticali presenti, anzi a volte abbiamo fatto esercizi di individuare gli errori in questo tipo di testi o registrazioni.

Comment: @Bruno9779: Per questa regione dobbiamo usare a lezione esempi di uso della lingua provenienti da queste fonti che ti dispiacciono tanto.

Comment: @Bruno9779: Ma se credi che questi registri della lingua siano fuori tema, forse è qualcosa da discutere sul Meta e non qui.

Comment: @egreg: Questo è quello che pensa la mia insegnante d'italiano. È vero: non si tratta di un italiano proprio esemplare, ma è un esempio tipico di un certo stile giornalistico che purtroppo si trova sempre di più. Le notizie si scrivono molto in fretta e vieni fuori un italiano poco accurato. Come studente di livello C1 dovrei essere consapevole di questo fatto. 
(cont.)

Comment: (cont.) La preposizione dovrebbe essere "da" e non "di". L'espressione è bruttina, ma potrebbe avere qualche senso. Le persone pagano per poter ascoltare la Consoli in un concerto e poi aspettano che qualcosa gli venga restituito. L'articolo afferma che non sono concessioni quello che viene restituito a queste persone, ma tutt'altra cosa. Non lo so spiegare molto bene perché, a dire il vero, continuo a non capirne del tutto il senso.

Comment: @Charo Una ricerca con Google di `senza fare concessioni di restituire` mostra solo questa discussione e qualche collegamento all'articolo a cui ti riferisci. È sgrammaticato, non posso dire altro se non provare, come ho già fatto, a trovarne un senso. Chiamare *utente* chi va a un concerto è indice di povertà lessicale, mascherata da qualche parolone.

Comment: @egreg:  Questo non lo metto in dubbio. Succede però che, come studentessa del livello C1, quello che si aspetta di me è che sia capace di fare lo sforzo di capire anche gli italiani che non si esprimono molto bene in italiano (e questo articolo ne sarebbe un esempio). Per farti un'idea faccio un esempio: abbiamo svolto un esercizio con domande di comprensione di quello che dicono gli intervistati in [questo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEwF-9FpOdU). Così sono i piani di studio ufficiali per la lingua italiana, stabiliti dal governo catalano.

Comment: Spiacente, ma se nemmeno un madrelingua istruito (come immodestamente mi ritengo) riesce a capire il senso di una frase, c'è poco da fare.

Comment: @egreg: Tuttavia, i vostri commenti da madrelingua sono preziosi per me per poter capire ed essere consapevole di questo fenomeno linguistico caratteristico di un certo modo di fare giornalismo (di cui penso sia un buon esempio questo articolo e, in particolare, l'espressione oggetto della mia domanda): articoli scritti in fretta e furia in modo che ne vieni fuori un italiano molto poco accurato, ma infarcito da paroloni con l'obbiettivo di mascherare questo fatto. Penso che una risposta alla mia domanda dovrebbe parlare di questo fenomeno.

Comment: @Charo, Bruno a detto 'OP', vuol dire, 'Original Poster', vuol dire, 'Charo' - non 'OT' = off-topic. Ma, tutt'insieme, è OT perche non è una espressione italiana, invece un errore. Si un testo da quel sito web te sembra strano, è piuttosto un errore che una scelta stilistica. (Scusate il mio stesso italianesco.)

Comment: @entonio: Come ho già detto, penso non abbia senso allungare questa discussione qui. Sono cose da discutere sul Meta. In ogni modo, la mia insegnante non la pensa come te: si tratta di italiano cattivo, ma è italiano. Se non fosse così, si potrebbe dire che una parte importante degli italiani (a cominciare da molti politici) non parla italiano.

Comment: @egreg: Succede che l'[autore dell'articolo](http://www.voglioviverecosi.com/spaghettibcn-il-blog-degli-italiani-di-barcellona.html) è un analista programmatore che si occupa di applicazioni web, gestione di siti, marketing online, ecc. Quindi probabilmente, a causa del suo lavoro, è abituato a chiamare le persone "utenti".

Comment: Personalmente ritengo che il resto dell'articolo sia scritto in un italiano carente, il cosiddetto “italiano dei semicolti” che in altri tempi era relegato a diari, lettere e testi privati. Ma la specifica espressione in questione è così aliena che mi sembra non solo errata, ma proprio lacunosa, come per esempio se inserendo il testo nel sito avessero saltato qualche parola (o se avessero usato un'espressione mal tradotta da un'altra lingua).

Answer (score -2):

SENZA FARE CONCESSIONI DI RESTITUIRE ALL'UTENTE significa che "non restituisce all'utente" cioè non delude, è un prodotto di qualità.
Infatti si dice "restituire all'utente" parlando di un prodotto di bassa qualità. Io avrei usato la parola "mittente" invece che "utente" però ho sentito questa frase usata anche con questa parola.

Ecco degli esempi:

Produce un vino di altissima qualità senza fare concessioni di restituire all'utente.

Comunque io non userei questa espressione perché è un italiano un po' antiquato. È come dire "ella" invece di "lei", suona fuori tempo.

Immagino che la frase che tu hai riportato sia tratta da un articolo sulla cantante Carmen Consoli. Molti giornalisti italiani usano frasi saccenti giusto per fare sfoggio di sapienza. Sinceramente lo trovo stupido.

Ciao! :)

Comment: Più che antiquata a me la frase sembra scorretta (e in generale quell'articolo non brilla per la maestria della grammatica).

Comment: Mi dispiace ma la frase di per se' e' corretta, anche grammaticalmente. E' solo molto antiquata e anche un po' "pesante". Comunque ognuno ha le sue opinioni naturalmente. E' una frase di un articolo su la cantante italiana Carmen Consoli. Ecco qui il link dell'articolo. http://spaghettibcn.com/20170202_carmen-consoli-concerto-barcellona-ciclo-jamboritalia.html

Comment: Non ho votato -1 e premesso che si tratta di opinioni, l'hai letto l'articolo? Non riescono a fare due frasi di fila senza sbagliare qualche concordanza. Inoltre la tua spiegazione non mi convince per niente: hai qualche riferimento per la frase "restituire all'utente/mittente" con come significato "fornire un prodotto di bassa qualità"? Testi antiquati ne ho letti tanti ma non riesco a dare un significato coerente a quella frase.

Comment: Sono pronto a ricredermi se sbaglio, ma così com'è questa risposta sembra del tutto fantasiosa. Esiste la frase idiomatica “rispedire al mittente”, nel senso di rifiutare una proposta e simili, ma visto che cambiano il verbo, il nome e il senso, non è quella. E persino se in qualche mondo possibile avesse senso “restituire all'utente”, anche “senza fare concessioni di” non sta né in cielo né in terra.